# The man's use of "honey" to a woman

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural for a man to call a woman "honey"? It seems to me that the word is mostly used by a woman to call a man, in an intimate relationship.

But I wonder if it is strange or not for male to use the word.

Comment: I think most endearments are gender-neutral, actually.

Comment: The term is reasonably neutral, gender-wise.  A woman can more easily get away with using the term to refer to a man, vs vice-versa -- it's less apt to be interpreted as a sexual come-on -- so the woman -> man reference is probably more common.  (I know I've had waitresses call me "honey".)

Comment: (I don't know about current practices, but in my parents' generation it was common for "honey" to be the term of endearment a husband used for his wife.)

Comment: For a boss to call an employee "honey" or "sweetie" might be considered, in the United States, to be contributing to a hostile work environment (regardless of gender).

Answer (score 1):

The first examples that come to my mind of a male addressing a woman as "honey" come from song lyrics.  These don't show whether addressing a man or a woman as "honey" is more common, but they do show that addressing a woman is not unheard of.

In The Archies' [Sugar Sugar,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar,_Sugar) the second and third lines are "Honey/ you are my candy girl."

In The Four Tops' [I Can't Help Myself,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Can%27t_Help_Myself_(Sugar_Pie_Honey_Bunch)) a man addresses his love as "Sugar Pie, Honey-Bunch."

Bobby Goldsboro's [Honey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_(Bobby_Goldsboro_song)) addresses a woman with "She was always young at heart.. Honey, I miss you."